# How to create custom Hibernate Session manager?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, threadpoolexecutor

I have a basic requirement :
1) Need a hibernate session manager which is called each time I open and close or do anything else using session.
2) It should work as a wrapper around the hibernate session.
3) For example : I create a session utility , which will allow at a time creating 5 sessions only , and if 5 of them are already in used , my request has to wait till I get one of the 5 session back.

Comment: your problem is little unclear. Any relevant code or reference will be helpful

Comment: As would any explanation of why you want to do this instead of using existing infrastructure that's already debugged.

Comment: This forum deals with specific Java coding issues. Typically, questions should be posted with sample code illustrating the issue. Your question is far too broad.

Comment: edited the question

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't a need to write a special *Session Manager* to do this as you can exploit a connection pool to easily handle this behavior for you.

What you first need to do is define your connection pool with a maximum number of available connections, which in your case would be **5**.  Then you want to configure the connection pool so that it has a wait timeout with something reasonable.  Just understand that this timeout can be problematic in a denial of service attack scenario, so use at your own risk.

With the connection pool properly configured, if the first 5 are doing some long-running task that takes several seconds and the 6th request comes in, it will wait to acquire a connection with the database from the pool before it continues, so you'll only ever have 5 concurrent connections happening with your database at any point.